# Best way to convert an esxi 3.1 virtual machine to hyper-v 2012 r2?

Tags: vmware-esxi, hyper-v

I know system center can migrate from esxi 4.0 to hyper-v, but I have esxi 3.1 virtual machines to convert.

Anyone faced the same problem?

Answer (score 4):

There should be little difference between an esxi 3.x and a 4.x VM.  Use the same MS tools that does a p2v.

SCVMM
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc764232.aspx

or

Disk2VHD
http://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/using-disk2vhd-for-physical-to-virtual-conversions-p2v/

These methods are completely independent of the hypervisor.

Comment: I always use disk2vhd, had problems with anything else.